# How do I find out what workshops are cluttered?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there any way to see a list of all [workshops](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Workshop) and their [clutteredness](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Clutter) at a glance?

Comment: ClutterOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely not an option to do this in the game itself, and I am not aware of a tool to do so.

In short: no.